# Continue loop through all tbody element and add id to all tr's

Tags: javascript, html

I have many tables and I want to give all tr's individual ids. I loop through all tbody but it only affects first tbody, not all of them. When I add loop indicating each tbody they work. Is there any efficient way available to loop through all tbody and give the tr's individual id. I want to do it using vanilla javascript, no jQuery.

My sample code here :

```
<table><tbody>
<tr><td>No.</td><td>Name</td><td>Score</td></tr>
<tr><td>01</td><td>ted</td><td>0.50</td></tr>
<tr><td>02</td><td>joe</td><td>0.25</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<table><tbody>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Address</td><td>Phone</td></tr>
<tr><td>joe</td><td>LA</td><td>012345</td></tr>
<tr><td>ted</td><td>NY</td><td>0124</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<table><tbody>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Spec</td><td>Budget</td></tr>
<tr><td>joe</td><td>i5</td><td>458</td></tr>
<tr><td>ted</td><td>i7</td><td>768</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Javascript :

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
var _trIndex = 1;

for ( i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
  var x = c[i].rows; 
  for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    x[i].setAttribute('id','tr'+_trIndex++)
  }
}
```

Second Try :

```
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
var _trIndex = 1;

for ( i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
  var x = c[0].rows; 
  for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    x[i].setAttribute('id','tr'+_trIndex++)
  }
  var y = c[1].rows;
  for (i=0; i<y.length; i++){
    y[i].setAttribute('id','tr'+_trIndex++)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the variable i in all the loops?

Comment: @mylee I forgot using different variables in loops. I'll keep in mind about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you need:

```
// Instead of getting the table bodies, I get only the table 
// rows inside the tbody elements.
var c = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

// Here I check if definitely the above query found any values.
if ( c ) {
  // Then I do the iteration to the found tr elements
  for ( i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    // And here I set the ID the same way you did in your example
    c[i].setAttribute('id','tr'+i);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>No.</td><td>Name</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    <tr><td>01</td><td>ted</td><td>0.50</td></tr>
    <tr><td>02</td><td>joe</td><td>0.25</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Address</td><td>Phone</td></tr>
    <tr><td>joe</td><td>LA</td><td>012345</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ted</td><td>NY</td><td>0124</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Spec</td><td>Budget</td></tr>
    <tr><td>joe</td><td>i5</td><td>458</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ted</td><td>i7</td><td>768</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you don't mind, do not forget to also upvote the answers that are correct ;) :) Thank you :)

Comment: yes. I upvoted. Due to lower reputation it isn't visible. But I have some queries. Can I loop through all of the tds in individual trs. and give them class of col1 to col3. @korefor-me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a single line of javascript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").forEach((element, index) => element.setAttribute("id", "tr" + index));
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>No.</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Score</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>No.</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Score</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>ted</td>
      <td>0.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>joe</td>
      <td>0.25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>joe</td>
      <td>LA</td>
      <td>012345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ted</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td>0124</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Spec</td>
      <td>Budget</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>joe</td>
      <td>i5</td>
      <td>458</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ted</td>
      <td>i7</td>
      <td>768</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In my original code, I have thead too. I don't want to affect the theads trs. that's why `querySelectorAll()` won't work for my case.

Comment: @abjim I adjusted the code and added a `thead` with `tr` to demonstrate

Comment: yeap brother, now It works fine. I found both of your answers helpful. Thanks. <3